# Logging in to the university website displays an entirely different user account

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, isp

*Note: I'm using Windows 7, Google Chrome as the default browser. We also don't have dedicated IPs in my country*

I was trying to register online to the fall semester online through the website of my university. I sign in, and the website says *Hello Fischer*, so I am indeed logged in to my account.

However, when I go to the registration page, it shows me the courses and the registration status of another student that i don't know - same university, different campus, and he's living in another city so he's not using the same ISP as me.

I thought it will be fixed by clearing the cache, so I opened an incognito tab. However, I still had the same issue. I tried it in my mobile, but no luck. Even my brother has the same issue - logging to his account from his laptop or mobile.

I told my brother to contact the IT guys at my university. He said the issue is caused by our ISP. So, I asked my neighbor for help, and he let me use his internet, on different ISP. This time, the issue was solved.

I reconnected to my ISP, and out of desperation, I did

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

It seemed to work at first, but this time, it showed me the courses and the registration statues of some other student, not the one I described above!

It's really the weirdest issue I have faced! So weird, I don't know what title I should use for my question, nor what tags to use! I simply don't know how to describe it!

Comment: Sounds more like an error being caused by your University due to a misbegot belief that an IP address is a unique personal identifier. There are so many ways this can fail, starting with NATted addresses, proxy service, etc.

Comment: @FiascoLabs ok I'll contact the IT guys at my university and see if they can fix it

Comment: or there's a mistake with student id numbers in the computer database...

Comment: @BenPlont if thats the case, why was the issue fixed when i was connected to another isp? and why did my brother face the same issue? is it possible? anyway i'm gonna contact the IT since you both agree that something is wrong with the website

Comment: I didn't catch that your brother was logging in under a different account. Sorry, I'm probably wrong.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a server-side issue, despite the differences in location/service-provider.